# Find pattern and edit text after the pattern using sed?

Tags: shell, scripting, sed

I have a file which consist of some text, my interest is this particular line :
BUILD = 0
where the value of BUILD keeps changing.

I need help in pattern searching for "BUILD = " and replace anything after this pattern with my new string.

For example:
BUILD = test

And also I want this editing to happen on the original file and no redirection.
How exactly can this be accomplished using sed ?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i 's/\(BUILD = \)\(.*\)/\1hello/g' test.txt
```

note: -i as in "in place"

Comment: Thanks for the help. My main challenge is for BUILD = old value, I am not aware of this value so the pattern searching can only consist of "BUILD = ". I need to put this in a shell script.

Comment: OK, I see, I edited my answer. I tried, now it works as you wished

Answer (score 1):

Here is some 'case-like' solution I came up with:

```
$ echo -e "0123\nBUILD = 2" | sed '/^BUILD =/ { s/0/a/; s/1/b/; s/2/c/; s/3/d/ }'
0123
BUILD = c
```

So the exact version of the command solving your problem is:

```
sed -i.bak '/^BUILD =/ { s/0/a/; s/1/b/; s/2/c/; s/3/d/ }' somefile.txt
```

The `-i.bak` option allows edit in place with backup to a file with `.bak` extension.